# How to retain a search keyword during Grails pagination?

Tags: grails, pagination

I have a simple Grails application. It has search form with one textfield and one submit button. If the results exceed the total number of 100, then Grails pagination appears and if I click on the second page's link, the call goes to the same controller's method, however, the search keyword is not passed this time (because the pagination is not the part of the search form) and it is not there in 'params'. How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass all your parameters to controller using `pageScope.variables`, like

```
<g:paginate params="${pageScope.variables}" total=.../>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. I think the issue is that my searchForm is a template and searchResults is another template. These 2 templates are part of a view i.e. they are embedded in show.gsp. So basically, searchResults template which has 'paginate' tag inside it, does not know about the 'keyword' which is in searchForm template. How can I access it?

Comment: Are you sending your search parameters back to the view?

Comment: I noticed that your way also works, but to access it the keyword, I have to use two level of indirection at controller side like params.params.keyword

I used following approach instead, thanks for the answer:
    params="${[keyword:pageScope.variables.params.keyword]}"

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your input field for search is say ***q***, then you can do something like this:

```
 <g:paginate controller="user" action="index" total="${total}" q="params.q"/>
```

This will retain your search keyword on to your paginated pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can send parameters in the paginate tag

```
<g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back"
        maxsteps="0" controller="book"
        action="list" total="${bookCount}"
        params="${[q:q, anotherParamether:anotherParamether]}" />
```

[Paginate documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html)